# I cannot see my commit history in gitlab branch because of error

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci

When I want to see my commit history in a specific branch, I only get this error:

[image: gitlab error]

I tried login out/in, erasing cache, loading page in different browsers (Brave, Firefox) and nothing seems to work out.

This only happens to newer branches, e.g. I can see commit history of 6 months old branch. Any help would be appreciated :3 .

Comment: Please indicate how you are looking at your commit history, i.e., what command or interface you're using.

Comment: And does `git log --all`  on the command line show the missing history?

Answer (score 0):

I would first check if I can clone the GitLab repository at all, and if, locally, those branches are there.

It also depends on if you are using an old private self-hosted GitLab instance, or if you are referring to the (always up-to-date) `gitlab.com` hosting service.

There was a similar error (about folder content instead of commit data) which was resolved with GitLab 12.8 (Feb. 2020)